# Which general methods are there for determining if $t$ and $e^t$, where $t$ is any given transcendental number, are algebraically independent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-independence

**Which general methods are there for determining if $t$ and $e^t$, where $t$ is any given transcendental number, are algebraically independent?**

**Can Schanuel's conjecture be used for this?**

We have [Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) and [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture).

But can these used for the two transcendental numbers without using algebraic numbers?

For Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem and Gelfond-Schneider theorem, algebraic numbers are a prerequisite of the theorem.

I want to determine the following transcendence degree:
$$\text{trdeg}_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{Q}\left(t,e^t\right).$$

But Schanuel's conjecture states only the lower limit $1$ of this transcendence degree.

My experience is:
If we want to use Schanuel's conjecture for determining the exact value of the transcendence degree, we have to give

- at least one non-zero algebraic number

  or
- a tower of elements whose tower of exponentials contains at least one non-zero algebraic number.

Are there further strategies for using Schanuel's conjecture?

Examples:

Let $a$ be a non-zero algebraic number.

The semicolon indicates that the exponential pictures follow.

$$\text{trdeg}_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{Q}\left(a;e^a\right)=\text{trdeg}_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{Q}\left(e^a\right)=1$$

$$\text{trdeg}_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{Q}\left(\ln(a),a;a,e^a\right)=\text{trdeg}_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{Q}\left(\ln(a),e^a\right)=2$$

But how can we determine the exact value of the transcendence degree
$$\text{trdeg}_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{Q}\left(t,e^t\right)?$$

I need that to find an answer for  [How to prove or disprove algebraic independence of exponential numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4656940/how-to-prove-or-disprove-algebraic-independence-of-exponential-numbers)